# how to read content-disposition headers from server response angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am unable to find, how to read filename from content disposition in angular 2 documentation. Can someone guide read the headers from server in angular 2[content headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3sVa.png)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try this kind of code here.

Note: Do not use map

```
this.http.post(URL, DATA)
  .subscribe((res) => {
     var headers = res.headers;
     console.log(headers); //<--- Check log for content disposition
     var contentDisposition = headers.get('content-disposition');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Partha Sarathi Ghosh for your great reply, it also seems to be working with map method

Comment: How to reach the same with `Promise` ?

Comment: doesn't work for me. Only content-type is in the headers

Comment: not working for me also.  Only content-type is in the headers

Comment: res.headers is undefined for me, but I can find filename in content-disposition of header

Answer (score 84):

With new Angular Http, one can try the following in the Service code.

```
  downloadLink(): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    return this.http.get<Blob>(this.someURL, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    });
  }
```

And use the above as

```
 this.someService
  .downloadLink()
  .subscribe(
    (resp: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
      console.log(resp.headers.get('content-disposition'));
      data = resp.body
    });
```

Also, on the server side, one needs to set the following header in response. `'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'`

Like in Java Spring Boot one can do the same using

```
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=1.xlsx");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION);
```

Comment: Thanks Nehal! This helped me. I was not exposing headers in response.

Comment: adding `observe: 'response'` makes my zip file corrupted

Comment: adding response type corrupting data

Comment: added on the server side as well,this is what i get in header keys `["cache-control", "content-length", "content-type", "expires", "pragma"]` but in browser `ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS: CONTENT_DISPOSITION` and `CONTENT_DISPOSITION: abc.xml` is present in my response headers

Comment: for .NET Core
    
`app.Use((ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");`

Answer (score 55):

To those complaining that the best solution is not working, and only content-type is in the headers, you need to set 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition' ON SERVER SIDE. I am using asp.net core, then I have to do the following.

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins(originsAllowed.ToArray())
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")
```

Answer (score 34):

In angular, we can read **File Name** like as show below,

```
  this.http.post(URL, DATA).subscribe(
        (res) => {
            var contentDisposition = res.headers.get('content-disposition');
            var filename = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('filename')[1].split('=')[1].trim();
            console.log(filename);
        });
```

But the main thing is that we need to specify **Access-Control-Expose-Header** in API as shown below,

**Note: The last line is mandatory**

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FILEPATH);

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = file.Name
};
response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
```

Comment: Please note that the code above is missing a replacement for the quotes which appear if the filename has custom characters in the name. You should add .replace(/\"/g, '') after .trim()

Comment: This will only work if the filename is the [1] element in the disposition string.

Answer (score 11):

**With Angular 9 and Expresss**

Need to Allow this header in Express

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Disposition');
```

Angular

```
this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
.subscribe((res: any) => {
    console.log(res.headers.get('content-disposition'));
});
```

Comment: for .NET Core
`app.Use((ctx, next) =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
`

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 7 the up-voted method don't work, you need to do it like this :

```
const responseHeaderFilename = response.headers.get('content-disposition');
```

Please find Angular official docs for more details: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

and also make sure that the "Content-Disposition" is exposed as in @mslugx answer

Answer (score 3):

To get the filename from response header.

```
(data)=>{  //the 'data' is response of file data with responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob.
    let filename = data.headers.get('content-disposition').split(';')[1].split('=')[1].replace(/\"/g, '')
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the filename is the [1] element in the disposition string.

Comment: Alternative : `decodeURI(response.headers.get('content-disposition')?.match(/(?<=filename(?:=|\*=(?:[\w\-]+'')))["']?(?<filename>[^"';\n]+)["']?/g)?.pop()?.replace(/\"/g, ''))`

Answer (score 2):

Angular 12 with parsing of the file name.

```
const saveAsWithServerName = (response: HttpResponse<Blob>, defaultName = 'NoName.pdf') => {
  const fileName = response.headers
    .get('content-disposition')
    .split(';')
    .map(h => h.trim())
    .filter(h => h.startsWith('filename='))
    .reduce(h => h.length === 1 ? h[0] : defaultName)
    .replace('filename=', '');
  saveAs(response.body, fileName);
};

this.http.post(`./api/ReportPdf`, request, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe({
    next: r => saveAsWithServerName(r)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

CORS requests only expose 6 headers :

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type Expires
- Last-Modified & Pragma.

In order to access custom headers with a CORS request, the server has to explicitly whitelist them. This can be done by sending the response header: **Access-Control-Expose-Headers**

Java :  **addExposedHeader** https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html

.NET CORE : **WithExposedHeaders** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Express JS : **exposedHeaders**  https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html