# Downloading file with FileSaver

Tags: angular, rest

I want to download file from my Rest API with FileSaver. In response headers in Content-Disposition I have filename. How can I read header in angular? 
When I set my service like this:

```
getPdf() {
return this.httpClient.get(this.url, {responseType: 'blob'}); }
```

I can download file without any problems, but when I want to set additionally {observe: 'response'} to read header in options I have error in my browser.

```
ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
at saveAs (FileSaver.js:112)
```

My function to save file:

```
this.packageService.getPdf().subscribe(
  pdf => {
     saveAs(pdf);
  }
);
```

I added Access-Control-Expose-Headers on my backend, only when i added {observe} there is an error so i can't find solution for this one.

Comment: on your backend, what is the url you are trying to hit? right now you are trying to do something like `localhost:8080/url` because you are passing in `'url'` ant not `this.url`. Also, have you checked out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33759534/8947748

Comment: sorry my mistake, there is this.url, and my url is localhost:8080/packages/{id}/raport, but there is no problem, because my problem shows when i want to read headers with {observe}. Without it file is downloading normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, when you request a response, it's not just data. So, when you are trying to directly pass it to filesaver it throws an exception.

I think this might work?

```
this.packageService.getPdf().subscribe(
  response => {
     saveAs(response.body);
  }
);
```

Comment: There isn't response.body (Property does not exist on type Blob). This code that i wrote is working and file is downloading, but I can't get headers from response. This error is showing when i add {observe: 'response'} in my service. Without it everything is fine.

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem, since I can't replicate the exact problem. But when I set my get method like this, I can read the header: getPdf()  {

    return this.httpClient.get(url, {
      observe: "response",
      responseType: "blob"});
  }

Comment: Also, there is this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887300/10934321

Comment: Okay I find an error. I was importing saveAs from 'file-saver/dist/FileSaver' not from 'file-saver' and this was producing error... Thank you for help.