# How to download csv file from the browser

Tags: c#, angular, csv

I want to download the file from the button click on the browser. When I click the button nothing is happening. I am temporarily storing the file in a local folder just to check the file and i can see the file being stored.

**API**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[controller]/downlaodCSV/{pID}/{customerID}")]
    public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage downlaodCSV(int pID, int customerID)
    {
        //getting the file
        var rateFilename = _Client.RateRepository.downlaodCSV(pID, customerID);
        
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            processing the stream.

            var result = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = rateFilename
                };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            return result;
    }
```

**Rates repository: this is my business logic**

```
    public string downlaodCSV(int pID, int customerID)
    {
        Random _random = new Random();
        int number = _random.Next(1, 9999);

        string fileName = "";
        try
        {   
            #region Dummy Data            
            //Dummy Data for now -- this will be changed by correct data from the API
            DataTable rates = new DataTable();
            rates.Clear();
            rates.Columns.Add("Name");
            rates.Columns.Add("Surname");

            DataRow dr = rates.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "Test1";
            dr["Surname"] = "Test2";
            rates.Rows.Add(dr);

            #endregion

            if (rates.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                string[] columnNames = rates.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>(). Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in rates.Rows)
                {
                    string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }

                fileName = CsvFilename(number);

                //Save to file to check the file. this will be deleted.
                string html = String.Empty;
                var newName = fileName;
                var path = @"C:\test\ " + newName + "";
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, stringBuilder.ToString());
                File.SetAttributes(fileName, FileAttributes.Normal);

                File.WriteAllText(path, html);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Rates data to download not found!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
       return fileName;
    }
```

**Component.ts**

```
downloadFile()
{
    try
    {
        var _pID = this.reseller.pID;
        var _customerID = this.reseller.customerID;
        
            //Now calling download service
            this.rateSheetService.downlaodCSV(_pID, _customerID).then((obj) => {
                console.log("Api call made!!");
            ///1
            let blob: Blob = obj as Blob;
            console.log("blob", blob);

            var binaryData = [];
            binaryData.push(blob);
            console.log("binaryData", binaryData);
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "text/csv"}))
            console.log("Url", url);

            });
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log("Checking the errors ", e)
    }
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
    public downlaodCSV(pID, customerID){
    return this.apiService.get<any>(`RateSheetReport/downlaodCSV/${pID}/${customerID}`);
}
```

**HTML**

```
     <button 
        class="context-download-button"
        (click)="downloadFile()"
        tooltipPosition="top">
        <span class="icon icon-download mr-5"></span>Download
    </button>
```

**Console log with the response am getting from browser**

[Blob console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0npWg.png)

Comment: Suggest correct spelling and case from `public downlaodCSV(pID, customerID){` to `public DownloadCSV(pID, customerID){`  Currently you have spelled "Download"two ways `(click)="downloadFile()"`

Comment: This is not an issue, it was my mistake and i have since fix it.

Answer (score 1):

try setting response type to `blob`:

```
return this.apiService.get<any>(`RateSheetReport/downlaodCSV/${pID}/${customerID}`, { responseType: 'blob' });
```

and then download it like so:

```
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  if (link.download !== undefined) {
    
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.setAttribute('download', 'csv.csv');
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
```

Also, try changing content type header to `text/csv` on the server

Comment: The file name comes from the API, not pre-defined, and from your example you have defined the file name. How do I then get the file name?

Comment: did you try it, is it working? if yes, the filename should be read from the header, so I'll update the code

Comment: please refer to the console log which shows the file

Comment: what for, it's not file/binary/blob. angular's default response is `json`, which is what you're getting. you need to change it to `blob`. try my code, if it doesn't work, then it's something on the server

Comment: I am getting: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

Comment: try logging response object, does it have a `Blob` somewhere, in `body`, that should be passed to `URL`, and now it's receiving some object, apparently..

Comment: I have updated the image with blob log @traynor

Comment: I don't see the actual file being sent.. I'm guessing it's something on the server, not familiar with c#, try perhaps this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889629/angular-7-unable-to-download-file-with-c-sharp-net-core-api

Comment: also, the file should download when manually accessing that route from the browser..

Comment: Will try to follow the example and see. How then do i get the file from the header? so that i don't hardcode the file name

Comment: read the header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898162/how-to-read-content-disposition-headers-from-server-response-angular-2

Answer (score -1):

Try to set attributes `href` and `download` on a `a` tag.

Comment: Will you be able to show me on how i can set it?